# Android add extra views to an ArrayAdapter that aren't from the array being adapted

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I would like to display a list of items in a `ListView`, and display an extra view at the bottom of the list (a "Get more" button) that isn't from the original array. I thought I could just override `getCount()` to return the size of my array plus one for the extra item, then in `getView()` I would build the custom view if the position paramater is greater than the number of elements, but I get a crash in `Choreographer.doCallbacks()` if the count I return is higher than that number of items in the list.

Is there something I'm missing? Or is there a better solution in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ListView.addFooterView()` is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an array adapter for this.  You need to write a custom adaptor.  It's fairly simple to do, it only requires 3 methods to write.